# How exactly does Perl handle operator chaining?

Tags: perl

So I have this bit of code that does not work:

```
print $userInput."\n" x $userInput2; #$userInput = string & $userInput2 is a integer
```

It prints it out once fine if the number is over 0 of course, but it doesn't print out the rest if the number is greater than 1. I come from a java background and I assume that it does the concatenation first, then the result will be what will multiply itself with the `x` operator. But of course that does not happen. Now it works when I do the following:

```
$userInput .= "\n";
print $userInput x $userInput2;
```

I am new to Perl so I'd like to understand exactly what goes on with chaining, and if I can even do so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're asking about *operator precedence*.  ("Chaining" usually refers to chaining of method calls, e.g. `$obj->foo->bar->baz`.)

The Perl documentation page [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity) starts off with a list of all the operators in order of precedence level.  `x` has the same precedence as other multiplication operators, and `.` has the same precedence as other addition operators, so of course `x` is evaluated first.  (i.e., it "has higher precedence" or "binds more tightly".)

As in Java you can resolve this with parentheses:

```
print(($userInput . "\n") x $userInput2);
```

Note that you need *two* pairs of parentheses here.  If you'd only used the inner parentheses, Perl would treat them as indicating the arguments to `print`, like this:

```
# THIS DOESN'T WORK
print($userInput . "\n") x $userInput2;
```

This would print the string *once*, then duplicate `print`'s return value some number of times.  Putting space before the `(` doesn't help since whitespace is generally optional and ignored.  In a way, this is another form of operator precedence: function calls bind more tightly than anything else.

If you really hate having more parentheses than strictly necessary, you can defeat Perl with the unary `+` operator:

```
print +($userInput . "\n") x $userInput2;
```

This separates the `print` from the `(`, so Perl knows the rest of the line is a single expression.  Unary `+` has no effect whatsoever; its primary use is exactly this sort of situation.

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks a lot for the explanation. I actually did try the parenthesis and just like you expected it was wrong because it was only one pair. But I thought I understood the Perl operator precedence. Guess not!

Comment: Or `print "$userInput\n" x $userInput2`

Answer (score 4):

This is [due to precedence of](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity) `.` (concatenation) operator being less than the `x` operator. So it ends up with:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $userInput = "line";
my $userInput2 = 2;
print $userInput.("\n" x $userInput2);
```

And outputs:

```
line[newline]
[newline]
```

This is what you want:

```
print (($userInput."\n") x $userInput2);
```

This prints out:

```
line
line
```

Comment: `x` has higher precedence.  higher precedence goes first.

Answer (score 3):

As has already been mentioned, this is a [precedence](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity) issue, in that the repetition operator `x` has higher precedence than the concatenation operator `.`. However, that is not all that's going on here, and also, the issue itself comes from a bad solution.

First off, when you say

```
print (($foo . "\n") x $count);
```

What you are doing is changing the context of the repetition operator to list context.

```
(LIST) x $count
```

The above statement really means this (if `$count == 3`):

```
print ( $foo . "\n", $foo . "\n", $foo . "\n" );  # list with 3 elements
```

From [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Multiplicative-Operators):

> Binary "x" is the repetition operator. In **scalar context** or if the left operand is not enclosed in parentheses, it returns **a string** consisting of the left operand repeated the number of times specified by the right operand. In **list context**, if the left operand is enclosed in parentheses or is a list formed by qw/STRING/, **it repeats the list**. If the right operand is zero or negative, it returns an empty string or an empty list, depending on the context.

The solution works as intended because `print` takes list arguments. However, if you had something else that takes scalar arguments, such as a subroutine:

```
foo(("text" . "\n") x 3);

sub foo {
    # @_ is now the list ("text\n", "text\n", "text\n");
    my ($string) = @_;   # error enters here
    # $string is now "text\n"
}
```

This is a subtle difference which might not always give the desired result.

A better solution for this particular case is to not use the concatenation operator at all, because it is redundant:

```
print "$foo\n" x $count;
```

Or even use more mundane methods:

```
for (0 .. $count) {
    print "$foo\n";
}
```

Or

```
use feature 'say'
...
say $foo for 0 .. $count;
```